# Does OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility preserve file checked out status?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

When migrating a project collection to VSTS using OVSMU should I have all files in the collection checked in?  In my testing OVSMU does not appear to preserve the file status.  Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. File status is not migrated over and Workspace configurations aren't either.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12852394)

Comment: @AtulkumarV.Jain I can't help it much. The answer is that it is expected behavior. There isn't much more to tell.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, that is what I expected. To ensure that all outstanding changes are preserved I will have the developers checkin or shelve their work.

Comment: I don't know whether shelvesets are migrated as well. I'd have them check in to be sure.